# How can I specify the QLineEdit input while typing

Tags: python, pyqt4, qlineedit, qregexp

I wanna specify the QLineEdit input while typing that if I set the **LineEdit** to write text only the user can't type any numbers or symbols and so on itried to write this

```
Name = QLineEdit(self)
regex = QRegExp('([A-Z]?[a-z])')
validator = QRegExpValidator(regex, self)
Name.setValidator(validator)
```

the QLineEdit me to write letters by the same sequance and cases like Aa or Bc please can you help me

Comment: What **exactly** are you trying to match with that regexp?

Comment: I want to allow user to write letters only

Comment: Give some examples of what you are trying to match. What about spaces? What about lower/upper case? What about non-ascii letters? Be precise.